# Counting checked items in database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

In my database I have table with multiple "yes/no" rows on which I would like to run some selection check if they are selected or not.

```
 ITEM      ORDERED       ORDER_ID
item1       true            1
item2       false           1
item3       true            2
item4       true            3
item5       true            4
item6       true            4
```

In datagridview in my code I will like to achieve this.

```
ORDER      STATUS
  1      not ordered
  2        ordered
  3        ordered
  4        ordered
```

In my code I will like to go through all orders and check if status of ordered items on that order is *true*. If all items on some order have status true, then i will like to set another flag that I have in ORDER table to *true(ordered)*. Which is the most elegant way to solve this problem? If you have some example of this like problem I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Point noted...Problem is that I can't find the proper way how to take items out of database, check ordered status on items in every order. Example...if order nr4 has 2 items and both are checked, then I would like to save result in some bolean variable. Should for this matter I work with dataset or is there more suitable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears `STATUS` means whether all rows for that `ORDER_ID` have `ORDERED = True`.  If that is correct, I think you can get what you need with an Access aggregate (`GROUP BY`) query.

True is stored as -1 and False is stored as 0.  So if the maximum `ORDERED` value for any `ORDER_ID` is 0, you know there is at least one item for that order which has not yet been ordered.  If the maximum is -1, then all items have been ordered.

Start with a query to determine `Max(ORDERED)` for each `ORDER_ID`.

```sql
SELECT y.ORDER_ID, Max(y.ORDERED) AS MaxOfORDERED
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY y.ORDER_ID;
```

Once you have that working, use it as a subquery in another with an `IIf` expression to transform `MaxOfORDERED` to the `STATUS` text you want.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.ORDER_ID,
    IIf(sub.MaxOfORDERED = 0, 'not ordered', 'ordered') AS STATUS
FROM
    (
        SELECT y.ORDER_ID, Max(y.ORDERED) AS MaxOfORDERED
        FROM YourTable21030926a AS y
        GROUP BY y.ORDER_ID
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.ORDER_ID;
```